# How to fix a error with array in bash script?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, syntax

This is a bash script I can run it normally

```
#!/bin/bash
array=$(awk '{print $4}' /var/log/httpd/access_log | uniq -c | cut -d[ -f1)
sum=0 
sum1=0
arr=(${array[*]}) 
echo "After unquoted expansion: ${#arr[*]}"

for (( i=1; i<${#arr[@]}; i++ )); 
do 
sum=$( expr $sum - ${arr[$i]} ) 
sum1=$( expr $sum1 + $sum ) 
done 
echo 
echo "Sum of \$arr = ${sum1}" 
exit $sum
```

but When I change

```
sum=$( expr $sum - ${arr[$i]} )
```

by

```
sum=$( expr ${arr[$i+1]} - ${arr[$i]} )
```

or

```
j=$( expr $i + 1) sum=$( expr ${arr[$j]} - ${arr[$i]} )
```

it has error: `expr: syntax error`

Comment: Change the shebang to `#!/bin/bash -x` to see how the commands are executed and to see the arguments of the `expr` when it fails. When you see it, you might know the answer yourself. Otherwise, add it to your post.

Comment: The assignment of `array` is not an array assignment!

Comment: when I use #!/bin/bash -x , I saw where the problem is. Thanks @janos a lot.

Comment: Instead of using `expr` you can do
`sum=$(( ${arr[$i+1]} - ${arr[$i]} ))` for arithmetic expansion. You could possibly also use `let` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the shebang to `#!/bin/bash -x` to see how the commands are executed and to see the arguments of the `expr` when it fails. When you see it, you might know the answer yourself. Otherwise, add it to your post.